# Uninstall newer version of Unison and install older version using OS X brew

Tags: macos, unison

Running Unison I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Received unexpected header from the server: expected "Unison 2.51 with OCaml>=4.01.2\n" but received "Unison 2.48\n\000\000\000\017", which differs at "Unison 2.4". This can happen because you have different versions of Unison installed on the client and server machines, or because your connection is failing and somebody is printing an error message, or because your remote login shell is printing something itself before starting Unison.

So I'd like to install Unison 2.48.3.

I previously installed Unison 2.51.2 version using MacPorts. I uninstalled the same using `sudo port -f uninstall unison`.  A few pre-built images of [Unison 2.48.3](http://unison-binaries.inria.fr/) available online are giving errors.

Comment: `which -a unison ` gives  `/opt/local/bin/unison `. The error message I get using that version is  `Fatal error: Received unexpected header from the server:
 expected "Unison 2.51 with OCaml>=4.01.2\n" but received "Unison 2.48\n\000\000\000\017", which differs at "Unison 2.4".
This can happen because you have different versions of Unison
installed on the client and server machines, or because
your connection is failing and somebody is printing an error
message, or because your remote login shell is printing
something itself before starting Unison. ` @slh

Comment: I used MacPorts for installing that.

Comment: I forgot to do that earlier thanks, I did `sudo port -f uninstall unison`, but now how to install the 2.48.3 version? Do you know a pre-built image of this?

Comment: Not yet, I need to install 2.48.3 version now.

Comment: It will be best if you [edit] your question to reflect that current status. You can check the Homebrew history, but the last 2.48.3 version is from 2015, so I doubt you can install that today. But I'm sure you can get the source code and try to compile it locally.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question now. I tried to built Unison 2.48.3 from scratch but I am getting errors in OCaml installation or in the end after I finish installing 2.48.3 version. Just found this "Unison does not work (and probably never will) on MacOS versions 8 or 9. " [here](https://itp.tugraz.at/Comp/Tutorial/soft.ext.access/unison/unison-manual.htm#download).

Comment: What does this have to do with MacOS 8 or 9? You are running macOS 10.x (formerly “Mac OS X”). If you run into specific errors while compiling, please show them (and all steps you took for compilation) in your question.

Comment: I don't know what it is with the version problem of Mac OS and Unison, but building it from scratch was not the easiest solution. I used rsync instead and it works just fine! @slhck